# Issue with Python Requests Library - SSL Error

Tags: python, http, ssl, python-requests, certifi

I'm currently working on a Python project where I'm using the requests library to make HTTP requests. However, I'm encountering an SSL error when trying to connect to a specific API endpoint. Here's the code snippet:

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/api/data'
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/data (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

I've tried updating the certifi package and setting verify=False in the request, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this SSL error and successfully make requests to the API?

Comment: this is an issue with the SSL certificate (presumably the credentials) . The code is fine.

Comment: *"and setting verify=False in the request"* - do you really get exactly the same error in this case? I would expect that it either works or that you get a different error, because this disables certificate validation which means it should no longer break due to a failing validation. Apart from that the reasons for the failure can be many: wrong server configuration, use of private CA, corporate TLS interception or antivirus ... . If you would provide the specific URL one could at least check if this is a server side problem - or try [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) yourself.

Comment: I think this is because the server doesn't have https. Try it without https. So `https://example.com/api/data` would become `http://example.com/api/data`.

Comment: better show real URL for this page - and we will test it.